# How can I draw lines behind the scatterplot generated by car::qqPlot?

Tags: r

[`car::qqPlot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html) plots

> ... empirical quantiles of a variable, or of studentized residuals from a linear model, against theoretical quantiles of a comparison distribution. Includes options not available in the qqnorm function.

By default, `qqPlot` generates a grid that overlays on associated scatter plot. `panel.first` argument is not accessible via [`qqPlot`](https://github.com/cran/car/blob/master/R/qqPlot.R). Using `plot.new`, I could plot a grid *behind* the points, but I have been unable to plot a grid with lines at specific positions: the line are positioned with respect to the first data point.

```
# fit model
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(200)
y <- rnorm(200)

model <- lm(y ~ x)

plot.new()
abline(v = seq(0, 1, 0.5), lwd = 2)    # This doesn't work as expected.
par(new=TRUE)
car::qqPlot(resid(model), id = FALSE, grid = FALSE, envelope = FALSE, line = "none",
            col = 2)
grid(nx = 3, col = "green")    # Plots grid in front of the points
```

[image]

Is there a way I could plot lines at specified positions relative to the data in the plot generated by `car::qqPlot(..., grid = FALSE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the plot first with `pch = NA`, so that the axis values are all set up appropriately but no points are drawn. *Then* draw your ablines (and grid if you wish), *then* set `new = TRUE` and plot the actual qq values:

```r
library(car)
#> Loading required package: carData

# fit model
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(200)
y <- rnorm(200)

model <- lm(y ~ x)

car::qqPlot(resid(model), id = FALSE, grid = FALSE, envelope = FALSE, 
            line = "none", col = 2, pch = NA)
abline(v = seq(0, 1, 0.5), lwd = 2) 
par(new = TRUE)
car::qqPlot(resid(model), id = FALSE, grid = FALSE, envelope = FALSE, 
            line = "none", col = 2)
```

[image]

Your vertical lines are now at x = 0, x = 0.5 and x = 1, as desired.

<sup>Created on 2023-08-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for `car:::qqPlot.default`, we see that the canvas is formed with

```r
    plot(z, ord.x, type = "n", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, main = main, 
        las = las, ylim = ylim)
```

so we can create an empty plot with the variables as formed within the function.

I'll use your `resid(model)` object initially, though inside `car:::qqPlot.default` it's the `x`.

```r
    ylim <- range(resid(model), na.rm = TRUE)
    index <- seq(along = resid(model))
    good <- !is.na(x)
    ord <- order(x[good])
    ord.x <- x[good][ord]
    n <- length(ord.x)
    P <- ppoints(n)
    z <- qnorm(P) # based on 'distribution'
```

With this, we can do this:

```r
plot(z, ord.x, ylim = ylim, type = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ann = FALSE, frame.plot = FALSE)
abline(v = seq(min(z), max(z), length.out = 3), lwd = 2)
grid(nx = 3, col = "green")    # Plots grid in front of the points
par(new=TRUE)
car::qqPlot(resid(model), id = FALSE, grid = FALSE, envelope = FALSE, line = "none",
            col = 2)
```

[image: qqPlot with grid under the points]

The extra arguments to `plot` are to ensure that *nothing* is plotted (no points, no frame, no titla, no axis labels/ticks, etc). While minor, this ensures that nothing is double-plotted when you again call `qqPlot`. For most displays this looks fine, but PDFs will have both sets of elements, and if there is anything at all different then they may appear overlaid or otherwise not quite right.

I assumed that you used `seq(0, 1, 0.5)` in order to counteract the fact that the coordinates on the first plot were not the same, so you aimed at what the default ranges (0,1 and 0,1). If you really want them at the *real* 0/0.5/1 in the plotted range, then go back to the original `abline`:

```r
# ...
abline(v = seq(0, 1, 0.5), lwd = 2)
# ...
```

[image]